# Finding which larger string contains a list of smaller strings

Tags: r, string

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I could not find anything on this and I everything I start doing ends up excessively complex.

I would like to find which strings if any are NOT in the list of smaller strings.

```
channels <- tolower(c("Digital","Social","TV","YouTube","Radio","OOH","Facebook","Reddit","Podcast"
,"Instagram","LinkedIn","Twitter","TikTok","Print","Cinema","VOD","OTS","xmedia"))

larger_strings <- c("weights_digital","weights_tv","weights_social","weights_ooh","weights_print",
"weights_appletv")
```

Desired Output:
This would be the selected output as 'appletv' is not part of the `channels` vector.

```
not_included <- "weights_appletv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `base R` option will be to split the larger_strings at `_`, loop over the `list` output from `strsplit`, check if `all` the values are not `%in%` channels to subset the larger_strings

```
larger_strings[sapply(strsplit(larger_strings, "_"), \(x) all(!x %in% channels))]
[1] "weights_appletv"
```

---

Or read as a two column data.frame, then `filter` with `if_any` on the columns and `unite` the rest of the rows filtered

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
read.table(text = larger_strings, header = FALSE, sep = "_") %>% 
  filter(!if_any(everything(), ~ .x %in% channels)) %>% 
  unite(V1, V1, V2) %>%
  pull(V1)
[1] "weights_appletv"
```

Comment: amazing thank you ill accept when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on `expand_grid`.

```
nn <- expand_grid(channels, larger_strings) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  filter(channels == str_sub(larger_strings, 9, -1)) |> 
  pull(larger_strings)

`%nin%`<- negate(`%in%`)
larger_strings[larger_strings %nin% nn]
# [1] "weights_appletv"
``
```